# Indexing a global dictionary from within a function

Tags: python, debugging, dictionary, global-variables

I'm having some trouble referencing elements within a global dictionary from within a function; the dictionary stores the URL of pages to minimise the need for multiple variable declarations.

here's my code:

```
import requests

page = {
'index':'http://www.exampleurl.co.uk/index.php',
'login':'http://www.exampleurl.co.uk/login.php',
'find':'http://www.exampleurl.co.uk/find.php',
'portfolio':'http://www.exampleurl.co.uk/portfolio.php'
}

def login():    
    with requests.Session() as c:

        c.get(page['login'])

        login_data = dict(email = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, submit = 'Login', cookie = 'yes')
        c.post(url, data = login_data, headers = {'Referer': page['index']})
        page = c.get(page['portfolio'])

        print page.content
```

The login() function has been tested previously and should hopefully not be an issue.

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    login()
  File "C:\Users\__\Desktop\__\script.py", line 22, in login
    c.get(page['login'])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'page' referenced before assignment
```

Any advice welcome

Comment: would work the first time but maybe not the second time because the global variable "page" is overwritten inside the function.

Comment: Globals are read only unless declared in the function - but you are getting the error because of the line page = c.get(page['portfolio']) this is being considered a local variable name the same as your global list so it throws the error on the line before where you try to read for the global list, just use a different name for the receiver variable

Comment: I don't see how it would work at all without using the global keyword. Can you not put it in the function?

Comment: Have you considered *not* using global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the receiver name:

```
def login():    
    with requests.Session() as c:

        c.get(page['login'])

        login_data = dict(email = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, submit = 'Login', cookie = 'yes')
        c.post(url, data = login_data, headers = {'Referer': page['index']})
        # this is the offending line
        page_ret = c.get(page['portfolio'])

        print page_ret.content
```

Comment: Sorted - Thanks folks!